# How to bind angular dynamic form?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have a dynamic form items in component.

```
  itemFormGroup = new FormGroup({
    x: new FormControl(4),
    y: new FormControl(1),
    z: new FormControl(0),
  });

  itemsForm = new FormGroup({
    items: new FormArray([
      this.itemFormGroup
    ])
  });
```

I want to bind this lines for input text.

```
<table class="table table-borderless" [formGroup]="itemsForm">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>x</th>
        <th>y</th>
        <th>z</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody formArrayName="items">
       <tr *ngFor="let item of items.controls; let i=index">
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" [formControlName]="item.x"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" [formControlName]="item.y"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" [formControlName]="item.z" disabled></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But this shows error on browser "Failed to compile."

```
Error: src/app/app.component.html:40:43 - error TS2339: Property 'items' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.

40            <tr *ngFor="let item of items.controls; let i=index">
```

Comment: can you provide an exact error output?

Comment: updated the post with error message

Comment: ok that seems obvious, well your itemsForm exist, but items only exist under itemsForm. So you have to access it via itemsForm.controls.get('items'). If you're using the formBuilder: this.itemsForm.get('items')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular is looking for `items` property in your component instance but can't find.

You can create a getter like:

```
get items() {
  return this.itemsForm.get('items') as FormArray;
}
```

Then replace your `ngFor` loop with the following:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
  <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" formControlName="x"></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" formControlName="y"></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" formControlName="z" [disabled]="true"></td>
</tr>
```

Note: I added `[formGroupName]="i"` to narrow context for Angular form and replaced `[formControlName]="item.x"` with string `formControlName="x"`

If you don't want to use typed version you can get rid of `get items()` in component and just use:

```
*ngFor="let item of $any(itemsForm.get('items')).controls; let i=index"
```

Comment: Ok this worked, but why need items() in controller?

Comment: You can use `items = this.itemsForm.get('items') as FormArray;` as well if you're sure that `items` FormArray is already registered.